# How jQuery is available outside the closure scope?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry if this type of question asked many times before but I'm little unclear with the jQuery coding here:

From http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

```
(function(global,factory){
  //some checks and coding
})(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function( window, noGlobal ) {
  //coding stuff
})
```

So, the jQuery is using the coding in that closure but how the jQuery is available outside that scope?

Comment: I don't see any jQuery here.

Comment: Yes, I too don't see the jQuery there but this is how jQuery is using as a wrapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the very end of this IEFE closure you can see the lines

```
// Expose jQuery and $ identifiers, even in
// AMD (#7102#comment:10, https://github.com/jquery/jquery/pull/557)
// and CommonJS for browser emulators (#13566)
if ( typeof noGlobal === strundefined ) {
    window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
}
```

where they export the `$` and `jQuery` identifiers to the global `window` object. This function with the `// coding stuff` itself is the second argument of the IEFE that you posted, and will - as the `factory` be called appropriately depending on what module loaders are available (or not).

Comment: uh! ok. so does it collide if I use var jQuery = 'foo' in my script? I mean from somewhere if jQuery is defined then jQuery would not work, right?

Comment: Only if your `var jQuery` is a global variable. But in that case, yes, you're overwriting jQuery (or jQuery is overwriting your `foo`).

Answer (score 1):

Inside of the closure you can find this [line of code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/jquery.js#L34):

```
return (window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery);
```

So jQuery constructor function is explicetly assigned to `window.jQuery`. That's why it's available outside.